# Lua: How to execute different blocks depending on conditions?

Tags: function, printing, lua, null, lua-table

I have this table:

```
no_table ={
        {a="3", b="22", c="18", d="ABC"},
        {a="4", b="12", c="25", d="ABC"},
        {a="5", b="15", c="16", d="CDE"},
               }
```

This function:

```
function testfoo()
    i = 1
    while no_table[i] ~= nil do
        foo(no_table[i])
        i = i + 1
    end
end
```

and the foo function:

```
function foo(a,b,c,d)
    if no_table[i][4] ~= no_table[i-1][4]
        then
           print (a+b)
    elseif no_table[i][4] == no_table[i-1][4]
        then
           print (b+c)
    end
end
```

Can you help me find? :

1. A way to be able to check if the two tables are or not equal (currently it gives me cannot index nil)
2. A way to execute only the "print (b+c)" code if the equality is true, or if is not true then both "print (a+b)" first and "print (b+c) secondly without duplicating the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of problems I'm seeing in this. First, I'd never rely on `i` being set in an external function, it really should be a local variable and passed as a parameter if you need it. That said, you need to check if `no_table[x]` exists before trying to access `no_table[x][y]`. So, for `foo` you'd have:

```
function foo(a,b,c,d)
    if not (no_table[i] and no_table[i-1] and no_table[i][4] == no_table[i-1][4])
        then
           print (a+b)
    elseif no_table[i] and no_table[i-1] and no_table[i][4] == no_table[i-1][4]
        then
           print (b+c)
    end
end
```

Also, for numbers in the table, if you want to do arithmetic, you need to remove the quotes:

```
no_table ={
        {a=3, b=22, c=18, d="ABC"},
        {a=4, b=12, c=25, d="ABC"},
        {a=5, b=15, c=16, d="CDE"},
               }
```

Next, in `testfoo`, you're passing a table, so you either need to split out the values of a, b, c, and d on your function call, or you can just pass the table itself and handle that in foo:

```
function foo(t)
    if not (no_table[i] and no_table[i-1] and no_table[i][4] == no_table[i-1][4])
        then
           print (t.a+t.b)
    elseif no_table[i] and no_table[i-1] and no_table[i][4] == no_table[i-1][4]
        then
           print (t.b+t.c)
    end
end
```

This results in:

```
> testfoo()
25
37
31
```

Edit: One final cleanup, since the conditions are the same, you can use an `else` rather than an `elseif`:

```
function foo(t)
    if no_table[i] and no_table[i-1] and no_table[i][4] == no_table[i-1][4]
        then
           print (t.b+t.c)
    else
           print (t.a+t.b)
    end
end
```

Comment: in no_table according to the current functions:     `no_table[i] = {a=3, b=22, c=18, d="ABC"}`     `no_table[i-1] --doesn't exists` , `no_table[i][4] = ABC` while `no_table[i-1][4] --doesn't exists either`.

Comment: @observ: not understanding your question there. `if no_table[x]` will return false if that entry in `no_table` does not exist.

Comment: basically my problem is when i try to do `no_table[i][4] ~= no_table[i-1][4]` because i-1 when running the script for the 1st time doesn't exists so it will attempt to compare something with nil. I've tried to do a `for i>=2 do if no_table[i][4] ~= no_table[i-1][4] then ` but it wont work eiter

Comment: You've got a logic error, not a Lua error. With the code you provided, it's worked around in the `if no_table[i] and no_table[i-1] and ... then ... else ... end`  code. Don't try to compare `no_table[i][4] ~= no_table[i-1][4]` before making sure the parent tables exist first.